# sveltekit build port is always 3000 but it is not available in my server. How do you change port in svelte.config.js?

Tags: sveltekit

Port 3000 is occupied in my hosting server. Now I'm building a sveltekit app.
When I use

```
npm run dev --port 4000
```

or npm run build and then

```
npm run preview --port 4000
```

I'm able to start the sveltekit using localhost:4000

My npm run build is always pointing me to

```
   skapp@0.0.1 preview
> svelte-kit preview


  SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.260

  network: not exposed
  local:   http://localhost:3000
```

after searching [online](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues) some of the possible solutions available online is to change the port in the adapter-node config env like so:

```
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            out : 'buildit',
             env : {
                port : 4000,
             }

            // vite : {
            //  server : {strictPort : false}
            // }

        }),         
    }
};    
export default config;
```

I go back and build the sveltekit again then run the command npm run preview again, like so:

```
npm run build
   npm run preview
```

but the it gives me the same 3000 port. Some of the discussion online pointed to the vite flag where you set the strictPort to false and it will look for the next available port but that didn't change the port and the build still fixated on port 3000.

When I use npm run build --port 4000, while another app is running on port 3000,  I get an error.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1503:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:8)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000
}
```

It seems like it is a server instance error. How to fix it?

It seems like fewer developers are interested in sveltekit because when I used to post a question about sapper, I used to get an answer within hours but I'm noticing that questions about sveltekit getting answered in days. Hopefully there are some developers out there keeping their eyes on sveltekit tag in stackoverflow.

So my question how to change the npm run build so the sveltekit app start using a different port. I'm not asking about npm run dev or npm run preview. My inquiry is about sveltekit to run on port 4000. How the npm run build could be used to build sveltekit app with a different port?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`svelte-kit dev` and `svelte-kit preview` are used for development and debugging purposes and should not be run for production builds.

when deploying to a server you run `svelte-kit build` to generate the final site (in your case that should be located in ./buildit)

i don't think that you can statically specify the port being used, but you can provide it when launching the server using an environment variable.

(i am using @sveltejs/adapter-node, so this might be different for other adapters)

```sh
PORT=1234 node buildit/index.js
```

i hope this is what you were asking for, to be honest i don't think i quite understood the question

Comment: Yes, that was the question. You provided the correct solution. Thank you.

Comment: @aarondiel I tried that same, but its not working for me. I'm also using adaptor-node.
Got some errors.

PORT=1234 node buildit/index.js
PORT=1234 : The term 'PORT=1234' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PORT=1234 node buildit/index.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PORT=1234:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Can you please let me know how to change default port 3000 to some other port?

Comment: ```PORT=1234 node buildit/index.js``` is not javascript, it is what you type in the commandline to execute the program, additionally the directory buildit comes from the config described in the question.
i do not think hard-coding the port into the javascript file is possible (using a environment variable is more convinient and is believed to be more secure)

Comment: Yes, I agree that. I understand first we need to set PORT from the command prompt then we need to give the command npm build run and npm start. This worked for me.

Comment: I have another issue, how do we deploy the svelte node app in a sub folder? https://qa.test.com/testing like this. I want to serve the app from testing

Answer (score 3):

After "npm run build", you can change the default port 3000 in the **build\index.js** file(Line 218).

> const port = env('PORT', !path && '3000');

->

> const port = env('PORT', !path && '1234');

Comment: that was excellent. Thank you for adding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

change the port mentioned at the bottom on the index.js that was created in build folder...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The port can be changed in the following ways.

#### 1. PROCESS.ENV

Setting the `"PORT"` environment variable will make the defined port used. For example you can execute the below to run on port `4000`.

```js
process.env["PORT"] = 4000;
```

#### 2. Edit index.js

The second option is to edit the `build/index.js:218`. Editing this line (218) to use the desired port works as well.

```js
// From
const port = env('PORT', !path && '3000');

// To
const port = env('PORT', !path && '4000');
```

I personally use the first option as it doesn't require me to edit the build code directly so I can save time. Look in the `env.js` file if you want to know how the `env()` function works.